# SQL Conditional Select Case logic

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, case, conditional-statements

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I have case statements in the SELECT statement and then I'm trying to perform GROUP BY and ORDER BY statements on this.

I have a result set based on a join between two tables. One is a table of students with ks2en, ks2ma and Ks2av columns with values 2c, 2b, 2a, 3c, 3b etc , the second is a table of results for each student eg A+, A, A-, B+ etc. The values in the ks2en, ks2ma and Ks2av columns are grouped and the results summed which give a grid of totals with levels down the left and results across the top. However the three types of level Ks2en, Ks2ma and Ks2av should bring through results based on a specific subject:

```
 Ks2en - English Result
 Ks2ma - Maths Result
 Ks2av - Any other subject Result
```

Where there is no value in the ks2en, ks2ma or ks2av columns I would like the group by to show as 'No KS2'.

My code at the bottom works fabulously for English against Ks2en, but I'm struggling to work out the logic to change the results based on whether the Subject is English, Maths or anything else.

The subject is populated via a variable called @SubjectName.

Below is pseudo code for what I would like my sql to do:

```
If @SubjectName = 'English' then
    If ks2en ='' then
        display 'No KS2'
    else Ks2en
    endif
Else if @SubjectName = 'Mathematics' then
    If ks2ma ='' then
        display 'No KS2'
    else Ks2ma
    endif
Else if @SubjectName <> 'English' and @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' then
    If ks2av ='' then
        display 'No KS2'
    else Ks2av
    endif
```

Here is my code so far that works when @SubjectName = 'English':

```
DECLARE 
@DataCollection varchar(50) = '2013/14 - Autumn 1 - Targets',
@StuYear VARCHAR(2) = '11',
@SubjectName varchar(100) ='English',
@TeachingGroup varchar(25) = 'Select All',
@SubGroup varchar(10) = 'Select All'
SELECT CASE WHEN Ks2en = '' and @SubjectName = 'English' THEN 'No KS2' ELSE ks2en END AS 'KS2',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result = '' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'No Level/Grade',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN ('U', '1a', '1b', '1c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '1/U',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN ('U', '2a', '2b', '2c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '2/U',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN ('G-','3c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '3c/G-',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN ('G', '3b') THEN 1 END),0) AS '3b/G',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN ('G+','3a') THEN 1 END),0) AS '3a/G+',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'F-','4c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '4c/F-',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'F', '4b') THEN 1 END),0) AS '4b/F',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'F+', '4a') THEN 1 END),0) AS '4a/F+',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'E-', '5c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '5c/E-',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'E', '5b') THEN 1 END),0) AS '5b/E',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'E+', '5a') THEN 1 END),0) AS '5a/E+',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'D-', '6c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '6c/D-',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'D', '6b') THEN 1 END),0) AS '6b/D',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'D+', '6a') THEN 1 END),0) AS '6a/D+',      
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'C-', '7c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '7c/C-',      
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'C', '7b') THEN 1 END),0) AS '7b/C',     
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'C+', '7a') THEN 1 END),0) AS '7a/C+',         
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'B-', '8c') THEN 1 END),0) AS '8c/B-',  
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'B', '8b') THEN 1 END),0) AS '8b/B',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result IN( 'B+', '8a') THEN 1 END),0) AS '8a/B+', 
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A-' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A-',
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A',
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A+' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A+',
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A*-' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A*-',
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A*' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A*'
  FROM student JOIN subject 
    ON subject.upn=student.upn 
WHERE
    [StuYear] = @StuYear AND
    [DataCollection] = @DataCollection AND
    [Name] = @SubjectName AND (
        @TeachingGroup = 'Select All' OR 
        [TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup
    ) AND (
       @SubGroup = 'Select All' OR
       Gender = CASE 
               WHEN @SubGroup = 'GenF' THEN 'F'
               WHEN @SubGroup = 'GenM' THEN 'M'
           END
    )
 GROUP BY ks2en
 ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ks2en = 'W' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    LEFT(ks2en, 1),
    RIGHT(ks2en, 1) DESC
```

If @SubjectName = 'Mathematics' then the statement would effectively do the same as the below:

```
DECLARE 
@DataCollection varchar(50) = '2013/14 - Autumn 1 - Targets',
@StuYear VARCHAR(2) = '11',
@SubjectName varchar(100) ='Mathematics',
@TeachingGroup varchar(25) = 'Select All',
@SubGroup varchar(10) = 'Select All'
SELECT CASE WHEN Ks2ma = '' and @SubjectName = 'Mathematics' THEN 'No KS2' ELSE ks2ma END AS 'KS2',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result = '' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'No Level/Grade',
**SNIP**
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A*' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A*'
  FROM student JOIN subject 
    ON subject.upn=student.upn 
WHERE
    [StuYear] = @StuYear AND
    [DataCollection] = @DataCollection AND
    [Name] = @SubjectName AND (
        @TeachingGroup = 'Select All' OR 
        [TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup
    ) AND (
       @SubGroup = 'Select All' OR
       Gender = CASE 
               WHEN @SubGroup = 'GenF' THEN 'F'
               WHEN @SubGroup = 'GenM' THEN 'M'
           END
    )
 GROUP BY ks2ma
 ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ks2ma = 'W' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    LEFT(ks2ma, 1),
    RIGHT(ks2ma, 1) DESC
```

If @SubjectName equals anything else eg Science, Art or Technology then the SQL would would like the following:

```
DECLARE 
@DataCollection varchar(50) = '2013/14 - Autumn 1 - Targets',
@StuYear VARCHAR(2) = '11',
@SubjectName varchar(100) ='Science',
@TeachingGroup varchar(25) = 'Select All',
@SubGroup varchar(10) = 'Select All'
SELECT CASE WHEN Ks2av = '' and @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' and @SubjectName <> 'English'  THEN 'No KS2' ELSE ks2av END AS 'KS2',
      nullif(count(CASE WHEN result = '' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'No Level/Grade',
**SNIP**
      nullif(count(CASE result WHEN 'A*' THEN 1 END),0) AS 'A*'
  FROM student JOIN subject 
    ON subject.upn=student.upn 
WHERE
    [StuYear] = @StuYear AND
    [DataCollection] = @DataCollection AND
    [Name] = @SubjectName AND (
        @TeachingGroup = 'Select All' OR 
        [TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup
    ) AND (
       @SubGroup = 'Select All' OR
       Gender = CASE 
               WHEN @SubGroup = 'GenF' THEN 'F'
               WHEN @SubGroup = 'GenM' THEN 'M'
           END
    )
 GROUP BY ks2av
 ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ks2av = 'W' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    LEFT(ks2av, 1),
    RIGHT(ks2av, 1) DESC
```

The grid my SQL produces looks similar to the below. The results set would look the smae however the background data would be based on the different criteria discussed above and would yield different totals in each cell:

```
KS2 No Result   1/U     2/U     3c/G-   3b/G    3a/G+   4c/F-   4b/F    **snip**
No  KS2         1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
2a  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2       1       **snip**
3c  1           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
3b  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1       NULL    **snip**
3a  1           NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
4c  NULL        1       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
4b  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
4a  NULL        1       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
5c  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
5b  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    **snip**
```

Comment: "***G-***"???  Wow, you have some tough grading there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you actually can deal with the task all by yourself except for the filtering. I mean, except for branching/conditioning the results by the "english/math/other", and your problem is with the fact they are almost identical except for that they come from different columns and you want to thread them uniformly.

Excuse me if it was not your actual problem, but I read/understood it that way.

I currently can't give you an exact full answer due to several reasons (i.e I don't know how the grades F+ G- etc relate to `3a` `6b` values ), but I can at least give you some help/startup how you can solve that kind of problems.

your wanted effect:

```
     If @SubjectName = 'English' then    If ks2en ='' then    ....
else If @SubjectName = 'Maths'   then    If ks2ma ='' then    ....
else                                     If ks2av ='' then    ....
```

it is easily done by some preliminary rearranging your input tables. Simply saying, just filter the interesting parts into chunks and add some constant value that will act as a handy metadata about that chunk:

```
          select "English"     as topic, ks2en as ks2
          from YourTable
          where ks2en <> ''
union all
          select "Mathematics" as topic, ks2ma as ks2
          from YourTable
          where ks2ma <> ''
union all
          select "Other"       as topic, ks2av as ks2
          from YourTable
          where ks2av <> ''
```

Note that I added an extra computed keyvalue called `topic` and that those data now are rearranged into 2 columns. You cannot now differentiate between `ks2en` and `ks2ma`, but you have one `ks2` and you can detect what it was from by the constant `topic` column.

Now:

```
select
    case when subq.ks2 = '' then 'No KS2'
    else subq.ks2
    end
from
(
          select "English"     as topic, ks2en as ks2 from YourTable where ks2en <> ''
union all select "Mathematics" as topic, ks2ma as ks2 from YourTable where ks2ma <> ''
union all select "Other"       as topic, ks2av as ks2 from YourTable where ks2av <> ''
) subq
where subq.topic = @SubjectName
```

(I've compacted the select/union part for overall readability)

will return you `KS2` for the actual `SubjectName` you wanted. Except the `Other` part that will obviously not match anything, as "Physics" does not match "Other". You can easily work it out by checking the SubjectName for known values and setting it to "Other". Or whatever else.

The point is that thanks to that preliminary filter-describe-and-glue-it-back you can reshape the data in any way you want and then easily group/project it into what you actually wanted.

EDIT: I don't know if it existed at sql2008 level, but I think you could also check the `PIVOT`/`UNPIVOT` operators that can transpose columns<->rows. They are tricky to use, have some limits that make them far less handy than they could be, but worth checking. Of course, assuming I understood the core of your problem well. Sorry if not.

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to answer. I've found it difficult to express my problem as simple as possible without missing anything. I'll have another look at my question and try and make it a little clearer what I'm after. I'll try using some example data.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want your `KS2` column to show the relevant KS2__ data for the relevant subject.  Try:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (Ks2en = '' and @SubjectName = 'English') 
         OR (Ks2ma = '' and @SubjectName = 'Mathematics') 
         OR (Ks2av = '' and @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' and @SubjectName <> 'English' ) 
    THEN 'No KS2' 
    ELSE CASE @SubjectName 
              WHEN 'English' THEN Ks2en 
              WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN Ks2ma 
              ELSE Ks2av 
         END
END AS KS2
```

You would use this clause (less the `AS KS2`) in the GROUP BY, and similar clauses in your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN
    CASE 
            WHEN (Ks2en = '' and @SubjectName = 'English') 
                 OR (Ks2ma = '' and @SubjectName = 'Mathematics') 
                 OR (Ks2av = '' and @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' and @SubjectName <> 'English' ) 
            THEN 'No KS2' 
            ELSE CASE @SubjectName 
                      WHEN 'English' THEN Ks2en 
                      WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN Ks2ma 
                      ELSE Ks2av 
                 END
        END = 'W' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    LEFT(CASE 
            WHEN (Ks2en = '' and @SubjectName = 'English') 
                 OR (Ks2ma = '' and @SubjectName = 'Mathematics') 
                 OR (Ks2av = '' and @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' and @SubjectName <> 'English' ) 
            THEN 'No KS2' 
            ELSE CASE @SubjectName 
                      WHEN 'English' THEN Ks2en 
                      WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN Ks2ma 
                      ELSE Ks2av 
                 END
        END, 1),
    RIGHT(CASE 
            WHEN (Ks2en = '' and @SubjectName = 'English') 
                 OR (Ks2ma = '' and @SubjectName = 'Mathematics') 
                 OR (Ks2av = '' and @SubjectName <> 'Mathematics' and @SubjectName <> 'English' ) 
            THEN 'No KS2' 
            ELSE CASE @SubjectName 
                      WHEN 'English' THEN Ks2en 
                      WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN Ks2ma 
                      ELSE Ks2av 
                 END
        END, 1) DESC
```